# How to Raise Error on @permission_required decorator in Function Based View

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to raise an error message if permission_required is failed on Function Based View?i want to raise error message instead redirect to login page, i know how to raise an error message in CBV but i don't know how to raise it in Function based view, Please Help Me.
Thanks and here is a code.

```py
@permission_required('request.user.projectuser.change_projectusermodel')
def update(request, id):
    test = User.objects.get(id=id)
    try:
        second_form = UpdateAccountDetailForm(request.POST or None, instance=test.profile)
    except:
        second_form = UpdateAccountDetailForm(request.POST or None)

    try:
        third_form = UserRoleForm(request.POST or None, instance=test.roles)
    except:
        third_form = UserRoleForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsersForm(request.POST, instance=test)
        form2 = second_form
        form3 = third_form
    else:
        form = UsersForm(instance=test)
        form2 = second_form
        form3 = third_form
    return save_all(request, form, form2, form3,'projectuser/update.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation section on permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) specifies how to do it: you have to call it with the `raise_exception` flag enabled: `@permission_required(..., raise_exception=True)`